# Is it possible to specify Action names dynamically at run time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, uri, action

```
string actionName = "Users";

[HttpGet]
[ActionName(actionName)]
public ActionResult GetMe()
{

}
```

...gives: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

That was just a test though, is there a way to do this? If so, I could re-use the same Controller and possibly create new URIs on the fly... right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

you could write a custom route handler:

```
public class MyRouteHander : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var rd = requestContext.RouteData;
        var action = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
        var controller = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(action, "users", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(controller, "home", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // The action name is dynamic
            string actionName = "Index";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = actionName;
        }
        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Finally associate the custom route handler in your route definitions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).RouteHandler = new MyRouteHander();
```

Now if you request `/home/users` it's the `Index` action of the `Home` controller that will be served.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take another routing argument in and do a switch statement.

Comment: If I did a switch statement wouldn't that mean that I need to know the URIs in advance?

Comment: well not exactly. you have the controller handle the routing manually.